# Single dependency in gemfile result on conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, conflict, gemfile

I'm new to Ruby and Rails and I'm trying to follow instruction for Spree, but I've encountered issue with dependency resolution when executing `bundle install`. I've googled a bunch of similar issues, but in all of them there several 'root' gems in gemfile. In my case I've single root `spree (~> 3.1.0.rc1)` and even the same dependency tree. It looks like single gem rails 4.2.6 depends on both versions of `actionpack` 5.0.2 and 4.2.6. How it's possible?

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
In Gemfile:
  spree (~> 3.1.0.rc1) was resolved to 3.1.0.rc1, which depends on
    spree_core (= 3.1.0.rc1) was resolved to 3.1.0.rc1, which depends on
      rails (~> 4.2.6) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
        actionpack (= 5.0.2)

  spree (~> 3.1.0.rc1) was resolved to 3.1.0.rc1, which depends on
    spree_core (= 3.1.0.rc1) was resolved to 3.1.0.rc1, which depends on
      rails (~> 4.2.6) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
        actionpack (= 5.0.2)

  spree (~> 3.1.0.rc1) was resolved to 3.1.0.rc1, which depends on
    spree_core (= 3.1.0.rc1) was resolved to 3.1.0.rc1, which depends on
      rails (~> 4.2.6) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
        actionpack (= 4.2.6)
```

P.S. I was able to solve my issue by specifying `gem 'rails', '>= 4.2.7'` in my gemfile. This still satisfy condition ~> 4.2.6 and doesn't contain issue described. But I'm still curious how it's possible described state.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you paste your `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using wrong versions of Rails and Spree that don't match, so they are incompatible with eachother.

Rails 5:

`gem 'spree', '~> 3.2.0'`

Rails 4:

`gem 'spree', '~> 3.1.0'`